# html form post gives empty array

Tags: php, html, arrays, post

I am trying to post data from html form (html code is inside index.php file) into add_student.php file which is supposed to just print `$_POST` array using `print_r` function. But there is always empty array on result.

**index.php**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="contact col-md-12" id="get_in_touch">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="contact_title">
            <h2>
                Add a student
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="contact_container">
            <div class="contact_form col-md-8">
                <form action="add_student.php" method="post">
                    <input name="student_name"   type="text"  placeholder="FULL NAME" class="input1"/>
                    <input name="student_email"  type="text"  placeholder="E-MAIL" class="input1"/>
                    <input name="password"  type="text"  placeholder="PASSWORD" class="input1"/>
                    <input name="major"  type="text"  placeholder="MAJOR" class="input1"/>
                    <input name="group"  type="text"  placeholder="GROUP NUMBER" class="input1"/>
                    <input name="submit"  type="submit" value="ADD STUDENT"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

**add_student.php**:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Why I always get empty array?

Comment: Could you paste the `add_student.php` file ? Just for further debugging

Comment: so any idea why it doesn't work for me?

Comment: It seems to be working for me to. Verify that the names of both your files are correct and that the files are in the same folder. Also how are you trying to host this? Through a LAMP/MAMP/XAMPP stack?

Comment: thank you for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that problem is in PHPStorm localhost port. When you just enter in browser the address of index.php it works perfectly. However when I run code from IDE it returns empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it will work if you use an include as the following:

```
include_once add_student.php;
```

And then use `index.php` as the form action. IF you later want to proceed to another page, add a `header <url>` at the bottom of the included script.

Make sure you check if the submit button has been pressed in the add_student.php script `isset($_POST['submit'])`
Data might get lost in the travel from to page